# Can't get GMSMapView to show zoom level 0. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: ios7, google-maps-sdk-ios

When using the following code zoom 0 - 2 never gets called:

```
GMSTileURLConstructor urls = ^(NSUInteger x, NSUInteger y, NSUInteger zoom) {

    NSString *tileTemplate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%tu_%tu_%tu.png",tileDirUrl,(zoom),x,y];
    NSLog(@"zoom : %tu",zoom);       
    return [NSURL URLWithString:tileTemplate];
};
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithTarget:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0, 0) zoom:0.0f];  
GMSMapView *mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];   
[mapView setMinZoom:0 maxZoom:5];
tileLayer_ = [GMSURLTileLayer tileLayerWithURLConstructor:urls];
tileLayer_.map = mapView;
[mapView setMapType:kGMSTypeNone];
```

My custom map is shown nicely centred but always at zoom level 3.0f
 (Even if I try to zoom out with a gesture I am locked at zoom level 3.0)

What do I have to do to make GMSMapView show a single 256x256 tile at zoom 0  and 2 tiles at zoom 1?

Comment: I just looked at [Map Bug Tracker][1]
Maybe its a Bug? Although since the issue is already nearly a year and its not acknowledged maybe it is not a bug?


  [1]: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5190&q=apitype:IosSDK%20zoom&sort=status&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars

Answer (score 1):

It will not allow you to zoom out further than the zoom level where both axises of the map covers the view, might that be it?

Comment: I think you are right! My custom image has a 3/1 width height relation. if I put the whole GMSMapView in a frame (0,80,300,200) I get zoom level 0 and see the whole image.Since I do not want to have a just 300x200 GMSMapView I am wondering if there is a way to see the whole image in a for example 320x480 GMSMapView... probably not easy?!

Comment: I'm afraid I've never dealt with map overlays on iOS, but my initial thought is that you might have to reconsider what you are actually trying to achieve, as both Map Kit and Google Maps SDK limit a bunch of stuff that is available via the web API.